# IOS converting hours to seconds from a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to convert a NSString into seconds, but i'm doing something wrong. This is my code:

The text in _myTextField, come from a uidatepicker in the format of HH:mm.

```
NSString *teste = [[NSString alloc]init];
teste = [_myTextField text];

NSDateFormatter *formatarteste = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[formatarteste setDateFormat:@"s"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc]init];

dateFromString = [formatarteste dateFromString:teste];

NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
```

i Always get i null result on the nslog. I tried to convert the dateFromString, back to a string before using NSLog, but still got a null message.

As requested here is more of the code i using:

I have a textfield that calls a uidatepicker, that is load on super viewdidload:

```
[_myTextField setText:@"03:00"];
UIDatePicker *datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
//[datepicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
[datepicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

[datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.myTextField setInputView:datepicker];
```

And this is the updateTextfield function:

```
 UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.myTextField.inputView;
 NSDateFormatter *formatar = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [formatar setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];


 NSString *textoDoField = [formatar stringFromDate:picker.date];
 self.myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textoDoField];
```

Comment: you are trying to get a date.. not converting string to seconds. you need to add more info on what you have and what kind of result you want

Comment: I have update the code, if you could take a look i would really appreciate. :)

Comment: "teste" is a string.  You are trying to convert that to an NSDate using a format string with only "s".  What does your input date actually look like??  (Hint, read the documentation on NSDateFormatter and [date format patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and do some Googling before you go any further.  Questions about date formatting are probably THE most common iOS question here and virtually every one is a dupe.)

Comment: According to the Unicode DateFormat Patterns, the "s" stands for seconds, i'm trying to transform the hours the user input lets say: 03:30 into seconds, so i cant set a reminder, using the dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys i was looking at this at wrong way, i did not need to transform the NSString into a NSDate.

I just need to get the NSString like 03:00, separate the "hours" from the "minutes", then, i multiple the hours x 3600 and the minutes x 60, to get the seconds in 3 hours for example.

The whole point of this was to create a Notification that run in a determinate time, using the [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: NUMBER OF SECONDS FOR THE NOTIFICATION APPEAR];

And thats it!

This is the code i using to get the Seconds, from the textfield string:

```
  NSArray *arrayWithNumberValue = [teste componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];



NSInteger valorHoras = [arrayWithNumberValue[0] intValue];
NSInteger valorMin = [arrayWithNumberValue[1] intValue];


NSInteger horasEmSegundos = valorHoras * 3600;
NSInteger minEmSegundos = valorMin * 60;


NSInteger proximoAlarme = horasEmSegundos + minEmSegundos;

manualTimer *horamanual = [[manualTimer alloc]init];
[horamanual tempoAlerta:&proximoAlarme];

NSLog(@"%ld", (long)proximoAlarme);
```

Answer (score 5):

One way (not necessarily the simplest) to calculate seconds since midnight from the time;

```
// NSString *teste = @"14:52";

NSDateFormatter *formatarteste = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatarteste setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[formatarteste setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [formatarteste dateFromString:teste];

NSTimeInterval interval = 
  [dateFromString timeIntervalSinceDate:
    [NSDate dateWithString: @"2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"]];

NSLog(@"%f", interval);

// >>> 53520
```

...or the somewhat more straight forward;

```
// NSString *teste = @"14:52";

int h,m;
const char *bytes = [teste UTF8String];
sscanf(bytes, "%d:%d", &h,&m);

int seconds = h*3600+m*60;

NSLog(@"%d", seconds);

// >>> 53520
```

Comment: What i trying actually  is to get the hours the user input lets say, 12:30, and then i want to create a reminder 12:30 hours later. So i need to convert the 12:30 hours into seconds, to use on my dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow ( guess i should mentioned that in the question. )

Comment: @André Hm, that's what it's calculating, `53520` seconds is 14 hours, 52 minutes which is what the sample string value says. Not sure what you want that is different :)